# How to keep label font size constant irrespective of slider change in Qt?

Tags: qt, user-interface, slider, label, slot

I want to display value of a slider by using the label in Qt. A slot function is called whenever the slider value is changed. The label value is updated in the slot function. At the moment it works, but not perfectly. **The problem** is: I have set the font size to 12 and bold in the label property. But whenever the slider is moved, the font size of the label becomes 8 and not bold. I solved this by adding `setPointSize` and `setBold` functions in the slot function. But is there an alternative, which could be more elegant? The following are the mainwindow.h :

```
private slots:
    void on_p_slider_sliderMoved(int position);
```

and mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::on_p_slider_sliderMoved(int position)
{
    ui->p_label->setNum(position);

    //more elegant method?
    QFont fontObj;
    fontObj.setPointSize(12);
    fontObj.setBold(true);
    ui->p_label->setFont(fontObj);
}
```

Comment: You can try to use [Qt Style Sheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html).

Comment: Try `ui->p_label->setText(QString::number(position));` and remove everything else in your slot. And do you set label text size and font in Designer or programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it setStyleSheet..

```
 lab = new QLabel(this);
 lab->setStyleSheet("background: rgb(255,255,255); color: #999999;"
                    "font-family: Arial; font-style: bold;  font-size: 12pt;");
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I insert the setStyleSheet method in the constructor. I changed the parameters, by taking reference to the setup in mainwindow.ui" The added line of code is: ui->p_label->setStyleSheet("color: black; font-size: 12pt; font-weight:600;");